# Displaying Date and Time information in script with format from spreadsheet

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a basic email-sending script in Google Sheets. I want to send email reminders on clicking a button, reminding people of an appointment at a date and time along with the location.

Everything works, except for the date is displayed in a confusing long form format:

The data shown in the date and time cells is:

> 8/27/2018
>   10:30 AM

The data being sent in the email is:

> Mon Aug 27 2018 15:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)
>   Sun Dec 31 1899 02:30:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)

I only need to show the date and time as written in the sheets. Is there a way to do this?

Another question is that one person might have more than one appointment, can I combine all appointments date/time for each unique email address into one email instead of multiple emails?

Adding code below:

```
function sendArticleCountEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("SSname"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B2:O2");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[0]; //email
    var recipient = rowData[1]; //name1
    var message2 = rowData[2]; //Name2
    var message3 = rowData[3]; //type
    var message4 = rowData[4]; //Appt Date
    var message5 = rowData[5]; //Appt Time
    var message6 = rowData[6]; //Appt type
    var message7 = rowData[7]; //Notes
    var message8 = rowData[8]; //Facility Name
    var message9 = rowData[9]; //Facility Address
    var message10 = rowData[10]; //City
    var message11 = rowData[11]; //Zip
    var message12 = rowData[12]; //Phone
    var message13 = rowData[13]; //Service
    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + 'This is a friendly reminder of your assignment tomorrow with:' + '\n\n' + message2 + ' at ' + message5 + '.'
      + '\n\n' + 'The assignment is located at ' + message8 + ', ' + message9 + ', ' + message10 + ', ' + message11 + '.' + '\n\n'
      + 'This assignment is noted as a ' + message6 + ' ' + message3 + ' ' + message13 + '. ' + message7 + '\n\n';
    var subject = 'Reminder: ' + message4 + ' ' + message5 + ' (' + message2 + ')';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

I think the problem is here, using either `var` or `rowData`.  The row is correct, just it doesn't pull the data in as shown in Sheets.

```
var message4 = rowData[4]; //Appt Date
var message5 = rowData[5]; //Appt Time
```

There is no time in the DATE cell (8/27/2018), so I'm guessing it defaults to "15:00:00" and because my data is input by mailparser, I don't have a method to change the format of the data.  Rather I hope I can use the data as displayed in Google Sheets and display this into the Gmail.

I appreciate your suggestions in advance, thanks!

Comment: If you have an issue with code, you should place said code in your question. Images of code are not acceptable.  Feel free to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on asking good code questions.

Comment: Consider using `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues` if you do not need the variables as anything except strings.

Comment: Right now it is sending one email per appointment but some people have 5-10 appointments and thus are getting 5-10 emails.  Is there a method to send 1 email with the details for all appointments with the same email address or same name?

Comment: That's a different question. Please do the [required research and make your attempts at solving the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and if you still have an issue then ask a new question. If your current issue is solved, consider posting the solution as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), or deleting the question if you think it will not be useful to others.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know how to choose your answer as the best answer. Please forgive me. But your advice did solve my issue. Thank you again!